# Isn't searches for dark matter crazy effort?

Tags: dark-matter

There are a lot of crazy quests in astrophysics, one of them is searches for dark matter. How someone could observe dark matter while it is far away?

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not a crazy effort. And no, dark matter absorbed by the underground experiments – many of them actually claim some evidence of such a new particle, see yesterday's update

> http://motls.blogspot.cz/2013/06/hooper-xenon100-may-see-dm-candidates.html?m=1

isn't far away. Dark matter penetrates every corner of every galaxy and it actually fills a larger volume (a dark matter halo) than the apparent volume of the galaxy as deduce from the visible matter.

At any rate, trillions (or a similarly large number) of dark matter particles are silently penetrating through your body every second.